# How to return dynamic List from WCF HTTP Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

```
  public List<dynamic> GetDynamicResult()
        {
            List<dynamic> lstDynamic = new List<dynamic>();
            lstDynamic.Add(new { ID = "1", Name = "ABC" });
            lstDynamic.Add(new { ID = "1", Name = "XYZ" });
            return lstDynamic;
        }
```

When i return List from WCF to ASP.NET web App using
`List<dynamic> lstDynamic = objClient.GetDynamicResult();` 
I get this error: `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly`

Answer (score 2):

WCF needs to define a DataContract (serialization is used) which is sent by wire. Using dynamic types conflict with this. You can use string combine with (de)serialization instead.

Comment: thank for ur reply it would be nice if u can gimme a simple example

Comment: For start change function to public string GetDynamicResult() { etc }. After that you can pack everything to XML and than to string. At client side you can unpack from string to XML and than to .NET object. [Very good link related for this topic](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chauhan_sonu57/SerializingObjects07202006065806AM/SerializingObjects.aspx)